# Primefaces Ajax action not triggering update

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the page below, everything works fine...

Except that after I click the delete button and hit "Yes Sure" in the Confirm Dialog My page doesn't change... It should show me the same form without that user.

I tryed a lot of things, but I am using Primefaces 3.0.M3
My form table is server created so it should be ajax usable.

Anyone got an idea what is wrong ?

Thanks !

```
                <h:form id="main" prependId="false">
                    <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userController.allUsers}" id="userTable">                                
                     <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{userController.onEditRow}" />                     

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            #{bundle.ListOfUsers}
                        </f:facet>  

                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.USERNAME}" style="width:110px">  
                            <p:cellEditor>  
                                <f:facet name="output">  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />  
                                </f:facet>  
                                <f:facet name="input"> 
                                        <p:inputText value="#{user.name}" style="width:110%"/>  
                                </f:facet>  
                            </p:cellEditor>  
                        </p:column>  


                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.Login}" style="width:100px">  
                            <p:cellEditor>  
                                <f:facet name="output">  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />  
                                </f:facet>  
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                     <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />  
                                </f:facet>  
                            </p:cellEditor>  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.Roles}" style="width:180px;">
                            <p:cellEditor>  
                                <f:facet name="output">  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{user.rolesCollection}"/>                                    
                                </f:facet>  
                                <f:facet name="input">
                                            <p:selectManyMenu  value="#{user.rolesCollection}"                                                        
                                                                               converter="rolesConverter"
                                                                               style=" width:100%;">
                                                    <f:selectItems value="#{roleController.listOfRoles}"                                                 
                                                            var="roles"   
                                                            itemLabel="#{roles.rolename}"  
                                                            itemValue="#{roles}" 
                                                    />  
                                            </p:selectManyMenu>
                                </f:facet>  
                            </p:cellEditor>  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.edit}" style="width:10px; overflow:visible;">  
                            <p:rowEditor/>                            
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="#{bundle.delete}" style="width:10px; overflow:visible;">                              

                            <p:commandButton update=":main" oncomplete="confirmation.show()" image="ui-icon ui-icon-close" title="Delete" >  
                                <f:param value="#{user.id}" name="userAction" />
                            </p:commandButton>  

                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure? user:#{param['userAction']} " width="500"  
                        header="Confirm" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation" >                        
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes sure" update="userTable" actionListener="#{userController.deleteAction( param['userAction'])}" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" >
                            <f:param name="userAction" value="#{param['userAction']}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton value="Not yet" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />                        
                    </p:confirmDialog>                   
                </h:form>
```

Here is the controller method

```
public void deleteAction(String id){

    userFacade.remove(userFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id)));

}
```

This method is being called and it's deleting the user.

Comment: It's unclear what part exactly isn't working. Does it invoke the action method? Does it return the expected ajax response? Are you reloading the list in the action method? Etc.

Comment: It's deleting the user all methods are getting invoked, but the update tag of the CommandButton on the confirmDialog is doing nothing. If I hit F5 and reload the page I get the new table without the deleted User

Comment: Not reloading the list in the actions method... and not returning anything on the method, I thought the update calling a DIV to refresh would trigger this reload of the List.

Comment: So, you are not reloading `allUsers` from the database after deleting the user from the database?

Comment: Is it needed ? I am asking to update the p:dataTable userTable, shouldn't this do that ?

Comment: No, I thought asking dataTable to refresh would trigger this behaviour...

Comment: Only the HTML will be updated, not the backing bean properties. You're responsible for that yourself in the bean's action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the `allUsers` list in the bean's action method after deleting the user.

```
public void deleteAction(String userId) {
    userService.delete(Long.valueOf(userId));
    allUsers = userService.list();
}
```

Otherwise JSF will just retrieve the original list. You're apparently prepopulating the list in the (post)constructor of a view scoped bean, that's why a F5 works.

Comment: Thanks got the idea, but allUsers is a method in UserController bean (RequestScope) returning the list to the Form... how can I refresh that ?

Comment: Uhm, you're talking about `getAllUsers()`? It just returns the `allUsers` property, right? You've just to update the property's value in the action method.

Comment: True thing... it's liked to the backend Bean. I am getting a hard time fixing this in my head :D Spring MVC is completely different. Thanks I think you are the JSF, Primefaces master here 90% of the questions I search got you answer on it. Thanks for that too !!!

Comment: If you use a normal action method instead of an action listener, then you can also navigate by a redirect instead, but that would cause a full page refresh. Spring MVC is as far as I know not ajax enabled, right?

Comment: Yeap not ajax enabled, you have to do it on your own...  but the main difference are the backing beans they are very different from Spring MVC controllers. Thanks for the info again !